# Get value from another table to create number leading trigger

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have `tblAutoIncreament` table to collect max number of ID before create trigger to add some number leading before insert row.

```
primary | nextNumber
 INT(2) | BIGINT(16)
--------|-----------
     10 |         50
     11 |         34
--------|-----------
```

So I need to get current `nextNumber` column to create trigger. but I don't know to to write them with correct syntax

```sql
SET NEW.foo = CONCAT(10, LPAD((SELECT nextNumber FROM tblAutoIncreament WHERE primary = 10), 14, '0'));
UPDATE tblAutoIncreament SET nextNumber = nextNumber + 1 WHERE primary = 10;
```

If the code above that's worked after insert new row in some table. It's should look like this.

```
                 foo | someColumn
          BIGINT(16) | 
  -------------------|-----------
  1000000000000050   | ...
  -------------------|-----------
* 1000000000000051   | ...
  -------------------|-----------
```

Can someone help me to make it, please?

Comment: MySQL or MariaDB... you tagged both

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . MariaDB is essentially a dialect of MySQL.  It is kept up-to-date with (almost all) changes made to MySQL.  I don't see a conflict in having both tags on a question (it is akin to tagging a question "sql-server" and "sql-server-2014").

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  True i know that MariaDB supports a dialect of MySQL ...But there are some differences between MySQL and MariaDB with trigger code.

Comment: I currently use MariaDB 10.1 ^-^

Comment: "max number of ID" -- which column is `ID`?  "before insert row"?  Is `primary=10` hardcoded?  The intent of the Trigger is too imprecise.

Comment: 10 is from primary and follow by 14 digits of nextNumber with zero leading. (10 and 14 digit of 51 with zero leading. )